# Gin-Rummy end-game considerations

Tags: end-game, gin-rummy

In Gin-Rummy, when you and/or the opponent getting close to the winning score (usually 100), how one should modify her play?

For example, I think, that if you just need few points in order to win then trying to Gin is a waste, better to go for a fast knock.

An answer might be divided into three cases:

1. I am close to Wining
2. Opponent is close to Wining
3. We are both close to Wining

The end-game might change the play in the following decisions:

- Pickup/Pass
- Pickup/Draw
- Which card to discard
- Knock fast / Gin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [rummytalk](http://rummytalk.com/keeping-under-count/) about the importance of keeping under the count:

> reduce the point total in your hand so that even if your opponent
>   should go gin, your total point count will be low enough so that he
>   will not win the game.